# SQL to get count in JSON data

Tags: sql, count

i am new to sql language. Could anyone sharing some point or solution for my cases?

i'll show the JSON data below, could it possible return some value in the column how many time appear in my json data. look like the table below:

```
+--------------------------------+
|column  |value    |totalCount   |
+--------------------------------+
|brand   |top-brand|  (2)        |
|brand   |low      |  (1)        |
|type    |Bobtail  |  (1)        |
|type    |Snowshoe |  (2)        |
+--------------------------------+
```

```json
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "cat",
  "type": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Snowshoe",
  },
  "brand": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "top-brand",
  }
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "cat",
  "type": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Snowshoe",
  },
  "brand": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "low",
  }
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "cat",
  "type": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bobtail",
  },
  "brand": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "top-brand",
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: Q: You realize that SQL is for querying "tables" in a ["relational database"](https://www.oracle.com/database/what-is-a-relational-database/), right? It's not for JSON.

Comment: My bad to said it JSON format, i guess all raw data are JSON. yes, you are right. it is relational database and i wanna query it from the tables.

Comment: 1.) you should tag your DBMS  2.) you should at least try and if you stumble problem, specific the problem in your question.  3.)  I believe there is a lot of doc about how to query JSON or how to unnest JSON. you should follow those doc first.

Comment: thanks for sharing, i just realise we can unnest JSON. I tried it before, i only could able to COUNT only one column. SELECT count(id), brand FROM Model GROUP BY brand. =(

Comment: Cool. I think why i getting error in multiple column groupBy, it must contain same value in SELECT =)